File not saving in downloads in android
Hi in the below file not storing anywhere and I am tried in all the places but file not exist.below code getting response Response:[B@1331d46 and sending byte array sending to the file and save it locally
Can any one help me where it got saved and what is issue with the below code
class ByteArrayRequest (
    method: Int,
    url: String,
    context: Context,
    jsonRequest: JSONObject?,
    listener: Response.Listener<ByteArray>,
    errorListener: Response.ErrorListener
) : JsonRequest<ByteArray>(method, url, jsonRequest?.toString(), listener, errorListener)
{
    private val headers: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()

    private val context = context

    fun addHeader(key: String, value: String) {
        headers[key] = value
    }


    override fun parseNetworkResponse(response: NetworkResponse): Response<ByteArray>? {

        return try {
            val data = response.data
            val file = createPdfFile(context) // Create the file before writing
            val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
            fileOutputStream.write(response.data)
            fileOutputStream.close()

            Response.success(
                response.data,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response)
            )
        } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
            Response.error(ParseError(e))

        }
    }

    override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
        return headers
    }

    private fun createPdfFile(context: Context): File {
        val fileDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
        val pdfFile = File(fileDir, "generated.pdf") // Replace with desired name
        if (!pdfFile.exists()) {
            pdfFile.createNewFile() // Create the file if it doesn't exist
        }
        return pdfFile
    }

}

fun submitdata(url: String) {

//new HttpsTrustManager().allowAllSSL();progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        val js = JSONObject()
        try {
            js.put("year", financialyear!!.selectedItem.toString().toInt())
            js.put("month", month!!.selectedItem.toString().toInt())
            js.put("emp_number", emp_num)
            Log.d("volley","js:${js}")

        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        val byteArrayRequest = ByteArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            url,
            applicationContext,
            js,
            { response ->
                // Handle the byte array response here
                Log.d("volley","Response:${response}")
                convertByteArrayToPdf(applicationContext,response)

            },
            { error ->
                Log.d("volley","Error:${error.message}")

            }

        )
        byteArrayRequest.retryPolicy = DefaultRetryPolicy(
            100000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
        )
        byteArrayRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + SharedPrefrence.getApitoken(applicationContext))
        byteArrayRequest.addHeader("x-api-key", SharedPrefrence.getApikey(applicationContext)!!)


// Add the request to a request queue
        val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext)
        requestQueue.add(byteArrayRequest)

    }
    private fun convertByteArrayToPdf(context: Context, byteArray: ByteArray) {
        val fileDir = applicationContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
        val pdfFile = File(fileDir, "generated.pdf") // Replace with desired name

        try {
            val fos = FileOutputStream(pdfFile)
            fos.write(byteArray)
            fos.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // Handle exception
        }
    }

file to be downloaded in phone

Since Android 11 you need to use either MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE (but there may be some problems with publishing your app with this permission in Google Play) to save your files in the external storage.
Or storage access framework: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files
// Request code for creating a PDF document.
const val CREATE_FILE = 1

private fun createFile(pickerInitialUri: Uri) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply {
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        type = "application/pdf"
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "invoice.pdf")

        // Optionally, specify a URI for the directory that should be opened in
        // the system file picker before your app creates the document.
        putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri)
    }
    startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_FILE)
}

